# Adding a Dropdown Menu to Advanced Search when I already have a Keyword Search

Tags: php, sql

I'm in the process of implementing an advanced search into my PHP code, so that a user can search within my table 'projects'

There is a series of things I want to allow a user to search by

Keyword,
Yes/No (Radio Button),
Dropdown Menu featuring all first names from another table

Now so far I have only implemented the keyword feature, which works. However, with all the additional features I want to implement I'm wondering if there is a way to implement the dropdown menu to aid in filtering a search.

Here is what I have.

```
<?php
include ('../resources/config.php');

$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.multiple, p.staffid, 
                s.firstname, s.surname
            FROM projects p
                JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = p.staffid";

$result = $db->query($sql);

//search feature implemented using SQL queries

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo '<p><strong>Search Results: </strong><p>';

$search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);

$sql .= " WHERE title LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

$sql .= " OR description LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

$sql .= " OR firstname LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

    }

    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

// output data of each row of the database table

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".substr($row['description'],0, 50)."....</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['multiple']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname'].' ' .$row['surname']."</td>";

    echo  "<td ><a class='btn btn-primary'   href='ProjectDetail.php?id=".$row['id']."'</a> View Project</td>";  

    echo  "<td ><a class='btn btn-danger'   href='deleteProject.php?id=".$row['id']."'</a> Delete</td>";  



  }

$db->close();
?>
```

To make things more complicated, the dropdown menu will hold all 'creators' of the projects. So the dropdown list must entail of all names within the STAFF table.

Sorry, I'm just unsure as how to implement this when already I have a keyword search.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And yes, there is a way to implement it - just do it.

Comment: I have tried following a few youtube tutorials though when I do, it breaks the Keyword advanced search. When really, I wanted them to work alongside eachother.. I tried creating a dropdown that searched for specifics rather than from values from a table also as I was unsure as to how to get the values from a table to search in my advanced search..thats all I've tried so far over the last few days